# Declarar variable using System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#

Tengo un detalle con la siguiente línea de código en C#, en mi clase de conexión, a la hora de declarar using System.Data.SqlClient me marca un error. La solución es que me falta el dll. Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema o que me diga donde puedo descargar el dll para agregarlo al proyecto. Gracias.

Comment: Estás usando visual studio? Qué versión? Un proyecto MVC? dot net core? consola? wpf?

Comment: Es la versión Visual Studio 2017 y lo estoy desarrollando en la arquitectura de capas con POO.

Comment: Visual studio es la ide, y que uses capas no es lo que te preguntaron. podrias mostrar el codigo completo de tu clase? y decir en que version de c# estas programando? de paso, mira por favor [ask]

Comment: Hola, agregaste la dll con nuget como dependencia?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que agregar la opcion `AddReference`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y buscas la libreria que quieres agregar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]